# When i repeatedly use my ajax function it skip some object

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I got a problem with my ajax call. I have made a single page application, with an array of questions. When you press next or previous, the view updates its content from the array. So if index is 0, and the user presses next, the view displays content from index 1. It does so without using any callbacks.

My problem is, that when the user hits next or previous I would like to save the answer they have inputted. I am using an ajax call to call a controller method which then saves the content.

```
    function SendObjectToController(object, callback) {

    if (object.question.questionFields[0].responseValue.length != 0) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data/postquestion",
            data: JSON.stringify(object),
            contentType: "application/json",
            processData: true,
            cache: false,
            success: callback,
        });
    }
}
```

When the user have finished all questions it should be saved in a database.
When I check the database for the questions, some are missing, even though the user answered every question.

I am 100% sure that all questions have been answered.

I have tried to do a success call, to check if it was succesfull or not. Everytime it returned success.

I am not experienced in ajax. But is it possible that I queue the method before it is done, and therefore does not update my database or? Any suggestions?

The way it works is.

The user answer question 1. Press next,  --> Next call SendObjectToController("with the object) --> and then update my index to display data from index 1.

Can the user overload my ajax call with simply being to fast to answer??

Comment: You need to disable the buttons and enable them in the callback so the user cannot click while ajax is running

Comment: But the user should be able to press the buttons, even though the ajax is running. Is it possible that i then need to make some sort of queue?

Comment: Yes. You need to queue them then

Comment: I think the problem is that your index value is not updated correctly (because there might be multiple parallel AJAX requests running at the same time). Are you  holding the index only in the frontend doing the synchronization in the `success` callback of the AJAX call? Maybe you should synchronize the index in the Database and take advantage of table locks to resolve the concurrency. Then your AJAX call can return the next valid index from the backend.